# Creating a new date using momentjs within a nodejs consumer

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, momentjs

I have a NodeJS RabbitMQ consumer which creates a date using MomentJS. However because this runs constantly, the date is always the same.

How can I create a new date every time the consumer receives a message?
Should I wrap the call to `moment.format()` within a function or do I need to use `new moment.format()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by initializing a new date when receiving a new message like

```
let newDate = new moment()
console.log(newDate.unix())
```

Edit: 
Also working without the new keyword

```
let newDate = moment()
```

but better for readability and preventing some possible strange effects

```
let newDate = moment(new Date())
```

Comment: Do I have to use the `new` keyword when creating a date?

Comment: It works also without the new keyword but imo it's better for readability reasons you could also do something like  let newDate = moment(new Date())